# how to make currency work in Facebook pixel, if the currency not supporting by Facebook ads?

Tags: php, facebook, pixel

My question is very simple, there is a list of the currencies which is accepted by Facebook pixel ads, but my currency is not there I am using the MAD for my eCommerce website, I have installed the module name **facebookproductad** it for the Prestashop platform. when I am trying to connect my account it's saying:

**Your account wasn't connected
The currency MAD currently associated with your website isn't supported on Facebook. Contact PrestaShop Social Media for support.**

Ok then i have contect to the module developer they said to the module file path and then there will be a file name with something(it's example) edit the file and on the `setCurrency` function if there is anywhere MAD change it to "MAD" now when I check the code there is the code like below:

```
public function setCurrency()
{
    if (!empty(FacebookProductAd::$conf['FPA_TRACK_ADD_CART_PAGE'])) {
        // get the currency code
        $this->sCurrency = parent::$sQuote . Context::getContext()->currency->iso_code . parent::$sQuote;
    }
}
```

Not there any **MAD** currency code so how I can on the `setCurrency` function and then how to make **MAD to "MAD"?**
it's important please guide me..advance thanks BTW I have tried to make it like this :

```
public function setCurrency()
{
    // get the currency code
    $this->sCurrency = parent::$sQuote . Context::getContext()->currency->iso_code . parent::$sQuote;
}
```

but still not working

Thanks for help in advance  if there any one please

Comment: What is changing from `MAD` to `"MAD"` supposed to achieve? Facebook simply does not support Moroccan dirham as a currency.

Comment: right but i have seen a website where its currency not in the list but its working and sending price in Euro if this will work that will be also fine

Comment: _"i have seen a website where its currency not in the list but its working"_ - what _exactly_ is working there, what currency do they send in their tracking? _"and sending price in Euro if this will work that will be also fine"_ - sure Euros will work, but then you will have to get whatever plugin you are using there to return the price _converted into_ Euros.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/233puiu   this is the website where currency on website is different add to cart working in pixel and the currency sending it in Euro and here is my website giving problem  https://prnt.sc/233q2g3

Comment: Yes, and? They are sending a currency that Facebook recognizes, and you don't ... but the latter was clear from the very beginning of this question already.

Comment: dear i have 2nd currency Euro, but i want my site in MAD which is already but need to send like Euro to facebook pixel

Comment: As I said, you will have to convert the price you have in MAD, to EUR then, and pass the EUR value to the pixel.

Comment: after pass, the value in EUR can I make it back again in MAD?

Comment: You don't need to change the actual currency in your cart, you just need to convert the value that gets passed to the pixel.